# Which HTTP method to use for Google Cloud Printing?

Tags: http, google-cloud-print

https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/appInterfaces#submit

In this documentation, several endpoints for Google Cloud Printing are presented. However, at no place is it explained which HTTP method to use, as in `GET`, `POST`, etc. How can one know which one to use? I'm specifically looking to use `/submit` and `/search` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

From the page you link to:

> Calling Syntax To use the interfaces, you need to prepend the Google
>   Cloud Print URL https://www.google.com/cloudprint to the interface
>   names, for example https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit.